# Space General incites a revolution

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, brian-herbert

This book is about a man who was once a powerful general in a space fleet. When he disobeys his President (who is female) she has him assigned to a planetary constellation that has no apparent value.

There he makes some friends and starts planning a revolution, his trump card being a valuable mineral used to chart pathways in space. The universe was running low on this mineral but his backwater constellation had a planet *stuffed* with this resource.

Added to the mix were awesome political agendas and an alien race thought to be extinct.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Hellhole by Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson - Book Cover]

Could be ["**Hellhole**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1155912) by Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson

Taken from a [review](http://timsbookreviews.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/hellhole-by-brian-herbert-and-kevin-j-anderson/):

> **General Tiber Adolphus has been exiled** to the Deep Zone planet of Hallholme, after his **failed attempt at overthrowing the Diadem
> Michella Duchenet** and the corrupt Constellation government.
> Hallholme is a planet in constant chaos and harsh conditions, the
> effects of an asteroid impact centuries ago.
>
> During his ten years in exile, Adolphus has been **planning for the
> day he can declare independence** from the Constellation.

Another section talks about the rare mineral/substance:

> With the discovery on the [allied] planet Candela of **iperion, a
> molecule that can be processed to help guide faster-than-light
> traveling spaceships**, he has been able to set up his own network of
> travel, with Hellhole as the initial hub.

How they stumble upon the ancient aliens:

> **Pools of oily water are discovered** that store the collective memories
> of the alien race that lived on Hellhole before the asteroid
> destroyed the planet.
>
> **The Xayan race dissolved their bodies** in the slickwater so that their
> memories could go on and so that the next life forms that came along
> might take on the personalities saved in the pools.

It's part of a trilogy. The second and third (as yet unpubished) books in the series are ["**Hellhole: Awakening**"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765322706) and ["**Hellhole: Inferno**"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765322714).

Read [excerpts](https://search.overdrive.com/media/332335/hellhole) from "**Hellhole**" (click on ‘Sample’). Or try this YouTube clip from the audiobook: